# How to Display Grid view data when the page is loading

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a gridview that have sql source and display some information. in addition to this, i have one text box and search button to control what is display in the grid view.

What I need is to know how to display both text box controller and gridview simultaneously when the page is loading.

Currently, only search box is display first and grid view data is next after some searching condition is meet.

Here is my markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UpdateDivision.aspx.cs" Inherits="Attendance_UpdateDivision" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div dir="ltr">

        &nbsp;Search Division&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDivision" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" 
            Width="198px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="61px" 
            onclick="btnSearch_Click" style="height: 26px" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:GridView ID="gvUpdateDivision" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
            DataKeyNames="DivisionId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" Width="448px">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB"/>                 
            <Columns>            
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionName" HeaderText="Search DivisionName" 
                SortExpression="DivisionName"/>
          <asp:TemplateField>
          <HeaderTemplate>

          </HeaderTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>          
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ATCF %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblDivisions] WHERE [DivisionId] = @DivisionId" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblDivisions] ([DivisionName]) VALUES (@DivisionName)" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblDivisions] WHERE ([DivisionName] = @DivisionName)" 



            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblDivisions] SET [DivisionName] = @DivisionName WHERE [DivisionId] = @DivisionId">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDivision" Name="DivisionName" 
                    PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DivisionId" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DivisionName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DivisionId" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DivisionName" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class Attendance_UpdateDivision : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvUpdateDivision.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvUpdateDivision.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Your fast support please

Comment: The datagrid should be visible by default (if it isnt, set the property in markup, not code behind) so drop that visible assignment in your code behind.  Id hazard a guess that your Data source is already binding for you and so you shouldnt have to call databind on the grid view itself.  Doing the stuff declaratively in markup usually saves you having to do any setup in code behind.

Comment: You should put a `emptydatatemplate` to see the results and then control the select parameter , it should only pass value when textbox is not empty.